# Java socket programming output stream doesn't send data to server

Tags: java, serversocket

I am using PrintWriter to write to the server stream, and then server sends back the data according to the command. This is all done in a client class and every command has its own method which is called one after the other. The issue is that after the first connection, server sends data but then for the second method, stream stops working, i have tried creating new instances of socket and streams but still not getting anything. No Runnable interface is used to send to or to receive from server. What could be that issue? I can post my code here but its a lot of code so I don't know if i should.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what do you say is the alternate for PrintWriter?

Comment: Did you FLUSH ??:>

Comment: Yes i am flushing the output stream. There is one thing though, in the first command, input stream is  passed to another class and that class handles the server input, make objects from string response. But after that, streams stop working when that class return the objects.

Comment: You saved my life man, BufferedWriter did the job.

Comment: @user16320675 if you post it as the answer, i will accept it. :) thank you again.